# In concurrent thread,how can we avoid duplicate uri in cts:uris()?

Tags: locking, marklogic

In a schedular ,which is running on all host at a time, right now I am using xdmp:lock-acquire to lock the collection, so that ,cts:uris will not pick the duplicate uris, but due to this scheduler is running in sequence .Is there any other alternative ,so that I avoid this lock, so that all run in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit unclear what you are trying to do, but it sounds like you have documents in the database that you are processing using a scheduled task, that runs on all hosts.  Your existing query makes it possible for two tasks to attempt to process the same document.

The easiest would be to generate a list of forests on the host that the task is running on using [xdmp:host-forests](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:host-forests), and passing that list into [cts:uris](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:uris) as `$forest-ids`

> **$forest-ids**   A sequence of IDs of forests to which the search will be
> constrained. An empty sequence means to search all forests in the
> database. The default is ().